# Dynamically appending translated text in Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate ,I have a link in Angular whose text value will be dynamic and should be translated, For example it should be of format 'Hello **XYZ**', 'Hello **ABC**' ,How can I pass params in the HTML template like '**ABC**' and '**XYZ**' such that link will be 'Hello **ABC**' and 'Hello **XYZ**' respectively.

```html
<div class="parent">

          <a class="link">

            {{ MYCONSTANTS.HELLO | translate}}

          </a>

 </div>
```

Here **MYCONSTANTS.HELLO** will have value 'Hello'

Answer (score 4):

ngx-translate supports parameters which you can pass dynamically. I suppose your json looks like below:

```
"HELLO": "HELLO {{param}}"
```

and we can render param dynamically, in your case

```
{{ MYCONSTANTS.HELLO | translate {param: abc  }}
```

In Component

```
abc: string = 'ABC'; //This can be dynamic
```

Comment: Same can be achieved through code using the following: this.translateService.instant('MESSAGES.VALIDATION.MAXLENGTH', {'length' : 6})

With "MESSAGES.VALIDATION.MAXLENGTH": "Maximum {{length}} characters allowed"

Comment: how to pass params as key from en-US.json e.g. `translate:{currency:'currency'}`? 
Suppose this `"currency:" "USD"` is mentioned in en-US.json

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="parent">

          <a class="link">

            {{ MYCONSTANTS.HELLO | translate}} {{ MYCONSTANTSPATH + '.foo' | translate }}

          </a>

 </div>
```

Comment: Hi MoxxiManagarm,Thanks for the reply,But ABC should be dynamic and should be translated as well,in this case we are just appending ABC.

Comment: edited, means you can dynamically edit the path string in template

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="parent">
  <a class="link">
    {{ MYCONSTANTS.HELLO | translate}} {{ abcVar | translate }}
  </a>
</div>
```

in ts file create a variable name 'abcVar'

```
let abcVar = 'ABC'
```

Let me know if you have any doubt

Answer (score 0):

In html file you can write like this to pass params:

```
 <a class="link" [translate]="'MYCONSTANTS.HELLO'" [translateParams]="{value: 'ABC'}"></a>
```

and in en.json file write like this:

```
 "MYCONSTANTS": {
    …
    "HELLO": "Hello {{value}}!"
 }
```

And here I have taken Static string as ABC, you can take variable and then assign value to it.